# Какова роль первого xargs в данной команде?

Tags: linux, bash, perl

Имеется команда:

```
echo T AV | xargs perl -E 'say join " ", shift..shift' | xargs -n 1
```

которая выводит буквы от T до Z, и от AA до AV. Но она работает, только если есть первый xargs. Скажите, пожалуйста, каким образом здесь отрабатывает первый xargs?

Comment: Напишите вместо *shift..shift* *T..AV*. Работает так же? (Понятно, что *echo T AV | xargs* надо удалить.

Comment: @0andriy, ну да, работает так же. Просто интересно почему xargs перед perl работает так же, как если бы я использовал ваш пример.

Comment: *xargs* старается уместить в одном запросе столь много аргументов, сколь позволяет соответствующая установка sysctl. К сожалению не помню как она называется по требованию POSIX.

Comment: *The command line for command is built up until it reaches a system-defined limit (unless the -n and -L options are used).  The specified command will be invoked as many times as necessary to use up the list of input items.*

Comment: Попробуйте читать документацию в следующий раз ;)

Comment: Всё, понял, спасибо большое за потраченное время, @0andriy.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что ответ на него дан  в комментариях.